# SQL retrieving filtered value in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, having

in this cust_id is a foreign key and *ords* returns the number of orders for every customers

```
SELECT cust_name, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Orders
    WHERE Orders.cust_id = Customers.cust_id
) AS ords
FROM Customers
```

The output is correct but i want to filter it to retrieve only the customers with less than a given amount of orders, i don't know how to filter the subquery *ords*, i tried `WHERE ords < 2` at the end of the code but it doesn't work and i've tried adding `AND COUNT(*)<2` after the cust_id comparison but it doesn't work. I am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HAVING clause (and use a join instead of a subquery).....

```
SELECT Customers.cust_id, Customers.cust_name, COUNT(*) ords
FROM Orders, Customers 
WHERE Orders.cust_id = Customers.cust_id
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*)<2
```

If you want to include people with zero orders you change the join to an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a correlated subquery here, because it calculates the value for each row which doesn't give a "good" performance. A better approach would be to use a regular query with joins, group by and having clause to apply your condition to groups.

Since your condition is to return only customers that have less than 2 orders, `left join` instead of `inner join` would be appropriate. It would return customers that have no orders as well (with 0 count).

```
select
  cust_name, count(*)
from
  customers c
  left join orders o on c.cust_id = o.cust_id
group by cust_name
having count(*) < 2
```

Comment: Customer name is unlikely to be required to be unique (you could have two customers both named "Joe"), so grouping on name alone would be bad (give wrong results)

Comment: How is it possible that you know the data OP has? Why do you think it's unlikely for this value to be unique? It could be a company full name which I find somehow unique. Anyways, you don't know the data model :)

Comment: I don't know for sure which is why I said "unlikely" -- but in most normalized data models, the name is not required to be unique which is why the join is using the id.   The nested query didn't have that problems, as it used the id without any aggregation on the outer table scan, however changing it to a join will change that semantics -- ultimately the person who knows the database design will have to make the call as to what is safe.